# how busybox (1.20.2) modprobe works? ( in poky )

Tags: kernel-module, busybox, openembedded, bitbake

I'm using yoctoproject's poky environment to create my images/packages for a custom machine. I was using an old branch, and now I want to update to dylan version.

Until now I had files in my /etc/modutils directory and when my machine started up it just probed those modules, everything was working fine.

Now it seems it works a bit differently. It doesn't probe 4 entries in that list. However when I'm deleting that whole directory it still probes those modules which was previously present. ( those 4 are still not probed )

My question: how is it working? where does it store previously probed modules?
With busybox 1.18.5 it was working fine... tough the list was separated into 2 files. Can anyone explain me how should I manage my modules? ( should I use /etc/modprobe.d? )

To tell the truth I didn't create this system, I just took over from someone. I couldn't find relevant articles after a fast search on google.

Comment: Here's the source code: http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/modutils/modprobe.c

Comment: Thank you Peter! Tough... I cannot find it in that source, but after some tries I found that if I'm placing my "mymachine.conf" file in the /etc/modules-load.d/ directory then it works.